# Sentry serverless - Cannot read property 'finish' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Good afternoon,

The sentry service works, But I'm getting this message in Amazon CloudWatch:

I'm using servelress-webpack to compile my files, In others projects was working normally.

Anyone knows what can be it?

```js
ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'finish' of undefined",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property 'finish' of undefined",
        "    at Runtime.eval [as handler] (webpack://rpc-analise-input/./node_modules/@sentry/serverless/esm/awslambda.js?:216:25)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"
    ]
}
```

My sentry file:

```js
import * as sentry from '@sentry/serverless';

sentry.AWSLambda.init({dsn: 'https://somedsn',
});

export default sentry;
```

My lambda file:

```js
import sentry from '../common/sentry';

const handler = async (event) => {}

exports.handler = sentry.AWSLambda.wrapHandler(handler);
```

Using webpack-serverless to compile everything.

The problem occurs on node_modules/@sentry/serverless/esm/awslambda.js

```
const transaction = startTransaction({
            name: context.functionName,
            op: 'awslambda.handler',
        });

Line 170: transaction.finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in a particular release of Sentry https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/2984

Until resolved, the solution is to downgrade.